# User logged in by sftp does not show up in `w`

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, users, sftp

My server is Centos 5. I have a chroot environment set up with the following in my sshd_config

```
Match group sftponly
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PasswordAuthentication yes
Match
```

When a user connects by sftp, a line is added to /var/log/secure:

```
Sep  3 15:30:20 servername sshd[26548]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user test by (uid=0)
```

However they are not present when executing `w`:

```
[root@servername home]# w
 15:30:47 up 156 days,  1:00,  3 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.18, 0.32
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mike     pts/1    12.34.56.78      Fri16    0.00s  0.10s  0.03s sshd: mike [priv]
```

But when users connect by SSH (like the user above), they are present. Is this standard behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man utmp`:

> The utmp file allows one to discover information about who is currently
>     using the system.  There may be more users currently using the  system,
>     because not all programs use utmp logging.

So, it must be that `sshd` is not adding an utmp entry when handling `scp` connections. Looks quite normal because `scp` instances are not interactive sessions.

Maybe something can be done using `ForceCommand` or `Subsystem` in `sshd_config`: It might be possible to wrap the execution of the `sftp` handler inside a login shell.

(Actually I wouldn't recommend that, better keep it simple and use standard logging facilities.)

Comment: The connections not being logged are `sftp`, not `scp`, so they are interactive.

Comment: Ok, it turns out you were right. Even though sftp seems to be interactive, it is considered to be non-interactive by the system and therefore doesn't add it to utmp for some reason, so the answer to my original question is, "Yes, this is standard behavior."

Comment: Yes, maybe they preferred to consider `sftp` as non interactive because its main use is `scp`. Using it repetitively might clutter the `wtmp` database.

Comment: Actually scp and sftp are different protocols. From Wikipedia, "Compared to the earlier SCP protocol, which allows only file transfers, the SFTP protocol allows for a range of operations on remote files – it is more like a remote file system protocol"