# Why does the 'w' command show phantom logged in users?

Tags: users

On Linux (Fedora 14), the "w" command says this:

```
[USERNAME@PC ~] w
 23:51:32 up 13 min,  7 users,  load average: 0,22, 0,42, 0,34
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
USERNAME        tty1     :0               23:39   12:49  30.71s  0.08s pam: gdm-password
USERNAME        pts/1    :0.0             23:39    9:39   0.01s  0.01s bash
USERNAME        pts/0    :0.0             23:51    0.00s  0.02s  0.00s w
[USERNAME@PC ~]
```

Why are there 7 logged in users when it only lists 3?

Comment: Duh! I didn't even know about `w`, shame on me!

Comment: This also applies to Ubuntu.

Comment: Weird. Doesn't happen on RHEL 5.4 on a few boxes I looked at (including one rather busy and one completely idle server).

Comment: What does `last|grep 'still logged in'` say?

Comment: Maybe you need to run it as root ?

Comment: w is in the procps package, there are several versions, make sure you have the latest. If you have the time you should download the source for procps and build it, iff you have the necessary build env and skills.

I skimmed through w.c and saw a few comments about the 'likely' need for a switch to show more info about invalid processes. Regardless on arch, ubuntu, centos, and suse I was only able to reproduce your output on one machine, ubuntu I think. w is a mashup of who, uname, uptime. Other than plain old intellectual curiosity, do you have a task to complete?

Comment: what's your output from `who` does it match?  what about output from `users`?

Comment: ..sorry, after rebooting the "w" shows good informations.. :\

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20074/14020) to [User logged in by sftp does not show up in `w`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20070/user-logged-in-by-sftp-does-not-show-up-in-w) suggests that `w` uses `utmp` logging - some digging shows that `utmp` is a file in `/var/run/utmp`.

If a program hasn't cleaned up `utmp` after logging to it, I suspect `w` may produce output like what you ran into.