# Does an SFTP login get accounted for with `last`?

Tags: ubuntu, last

At first glance it doesn't show, but I also just learned about the existence of `last` as well.

Comment: By `sftp` login, what do you mean? Have you configured to use your `sftp` to do something as discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110593/how-can-i-create-an-sftp-user-in-centos)?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: http://askubuntu.com/q/107602/158442, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20070/user-logged-in-by-sftp-does-not-show-up-in-w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you look in one of the log files in /var/log (depending on your syslog configuration settings) as this information will be there if configured appropriately.  last is basically only used when you run login.  If you do not find it, then an appropriate reconfiguration of syslog and/or sshd_config might be in order.